# Hide Objects behind Specific Plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders

I am trying to find ways to hide objects behind specific planes.

[image: "tv" with cube behind it.]

That is a "tv" with a cube behind it, I already have it so when you look at it front on, the back disappears.

[image: Back of "tv" gone]

However the effect is that of "Non-Euclidean geometry" so the blue cube shouldn't be seen outside of the tv, but if I add another transparent cube/plane and apply the same shader to the cube, its not going to work.

[image: new block off]

It is going to block off both the cube and the back of the tv, and now the cube doesn't show head on.

[image: no cube]

My question is, is it able to do it based on groups or plane id's? I know the shader is using directly the transparency values. but just not sure how else to do it.

These are the shaders:

[image: Transparent]

(Transparent Plane/Cube)

[image: Back of tv]

The tv back, and the blue cube (obviously blue color for cube)

Sincerely, Nota

Comment: Hello :). You want the blue cube to only be visible when seen through the 'TV' object? And be invisible on it's own?

Comment: Yeah basically :)

Answer (score 11):

I went to recycling [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200593/2214) and after simplifying I end up with the same node tree, that seems to me is working. So I guess I missed something ... so if you can explain missing part closer.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi yes, that is the effect I'm going for, but I wanted to know if it was possible to expand on that, something like this; https://i.imgur.com/haDQXeZ.mp4 I did this through rendering twice, and compositing them together in after effects.

Comment: @Nota I don't know if it can be done with a shader. I saw some paralax tech using Normals to get illusion of depth, but  I would go a compositing way as well (can be done in blender too.

Comment: Tried, then realize it only works in Cycles because Transparent Depth only works in Cycles, not Eevee.