# Depth Shading / Portal Effect

Tags: shaders

I'm trying to recreate a "Portal" effect which is similar to a Depth Shader used inside of Unity. I've seen many tutorials for doing something similar on Blender, although it seems most of these tutorials involve cutting out a hole in a plane and just using some camera tricks to achieve this illusion. Are there any other, more flexible solutions out there?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/214311/2214

Comment: What tutorial you used and what kind of more flexibility do you expect? From your image I'm not sure what I'm looking at ... What 0/1 means?

Comment: I just want to achieve this result without using a hole in the wall Approach . I want to achieve it using one object that could for example be moved around, seen from different angles, etc

Comment: I think the effect you're going for is related to _Interior Mapping_ which, although is technically possible in blender, it can be a real pain to pull off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the topic a bit more, my preferred solution was to use:

1. a holdout shader which renders everything behind it to be completely transparent
2. a multi-layer compositing process, where the objects to hide are separated from other objects in the background.

Answer (score 2):

By Camera trick you probably mean ...

### version Parallax Cube Mapping

it works like a magic for interior faked on plane with [cube texture mapping](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juI9Q_xgjh8)

[image]

Easily faked with Mask texture, but illusion becomes broken when observed in animation, because space behind the rift is cubish and doesn't follow rift edges.

[image]

[Here you can find](https://mrrolord.gumroad.com/l/dPYOk) a node group nicely organised.

### version Parallax Occlusion Mapping

In your case you should use a POM (parallax Occlusion Mapping) nodetree using a depth texture to layerevector into depth steps ... [simle example of technique](https://www.artstation.com/blogs/loftus/9B67/parallax-mapping-in-blender-part-1) ...

Here used only depth pass for the rift ... 32 layers

[image]

If I checked right [reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syQUbWF29sQ) ... Unity does the same ... with some specific amount of "layers" you affect just distance between them.

For the sword part technically hiden behind the plane is used Parallax CubeMap technique with shifted left right sides to center and textured by baked material.

[image]

64 layers ...
[image]

Texture on upper part of sword is not seamless, because  baked in separately (at home machine) ... sorry. And since sword texture in shader is just a plane it has not a thickness.

[image]

---

Anyway as conclusion - it seems to me much easier and precise just grab rift texture and use it as a transparency mask for a wall shader with Texture coordinates set to sword.

### version Transparent Mask

First drag&drop rift image into 3D view (as Empty Image), search for Trace GP to generate PG object from texture, W > Convert to Curve (than extrude curve or convert to mesh and extrude in edit mode).

[image]

**Wall (Plane material)**
Than use the same texture as *Factor* for *Mix Shader* of *Transparent* and *Diffuse* node with Texture Coordinates > Object > Empty ...

[image]

Parent all needed objects (rift object, sword, green light) to Empty.

[image]

[image]

Final result ...

[image]

[Blend file on Dropbox (skip Sign-in).](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lsvwhyrzsz9bpwt/test_Hole_Mask.blend?dl=0)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, parallax mapping is definitely the first part of the equation here. But iit's the sword object that I could find no tutorial on. It is placed outside of the plane. I would be interested in seeing your example

Comment: Appreciate you taking the time to put this together. So, do you think it would be possible to combine your approach with interior mapping? I'd like to avoid the extruded geometry and keep the floor plane flat

Comment: I did not succeed ... and even I would it would be too visible that hole doesn't match the edges of the rift. Answer extended parallax version with an example of a way it is used usually (sure smaller distance between layers smoother result).

Comment: after some more searching I think this may be the answer: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txUCkthVriw

Comment: Hm ... if that would be solution for you great ... it seams we targeted to different thing :) Please post it as answer to help others :) It is quite interesting topic ... BTW  I got working sword layer for parallax thing and for hole extended to 64 layers could be working with some limits I will update A when I merge those together.