# Possible to make a material that shows negative version of whatever's on the other side?

Tags: node-editor, eevee-render-engine, glass

kind of like a glass material, except anything that's shown through it is inverted, color wise.
is this possible to do with just nodes in eevee? here's an edit of what I'm trying to go for.
[image: mockup of what i'd want it to look like]

Comment: maybe in the Compositor with a mask and a Color > Invert node?

Comment: With [Lightpath node](https://youtu.be/MTFxyNzI5EE?t=1298) you can change color to be seen through glass, but I don't think you can get completely negative result... or you can try a [**negative light**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEzYS8Cx0Zw) combine with [this trick](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200593/2214) ... if it does something ... I don't have a time to test it now ... but I guess +1 to moonboots for Compositor would be the fastest way ...